# Restrict selected fields using Hibernate Criteria projection

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have an HQL query, but it has many where conditions. So I decided to use Hibernate Criteria.

Here is my query:

```
select distinct u.employee.id,u.employee.name,u.employee.address.phone from user u.
```

I tried it using the Criteria Project.property. But it gives an error. Is it possible to write Hibernate Criteria for this query?

Comment: Please include the error output. By the way, yes, it is possible.

Comment: @meskobalazs Could you please explain it how? I am new in hibernate

Comment: You said it gives an error, where? Also could you show us your criteria query?

Comment: Can you add code of your dataSet class ( class with fields: id, name...)? To create HQL you need to know names of fields in this class.

Answer (score 2):

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(User.class)
    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
      .add(Projections.property("employee.id"), "id")
      .add(Projections.property("employee.name"), "Name"));

  List<User> list = cr.list();
```

Few more examples.

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Employee.class);
```

// To get total row count.

```
cr.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
```

// To get average of a property.

```
cr.setProjection(Projections.avg("salary"));
```

// To get distinct count of a property.

```
cr.setProjection(Projections.countDistinct("firstName"));
```

// To get maximum of a property.

```
cr.setProjection(Projections.max("salary"));
```

// To get minimum of a property.

```
cr.setProjection(Projections.min("salary"));
```

// To get sum of a property.

```
cr.setProjection(Projections.sum("salary"));
```

Comment: it is not what i expected. I need to know how to use fields like user.employee.address.phone

Comment: @rohi `.add(Projections.property("user.employee.address.phone"), "phone"));`

Answer (score 1):

```
List<User> users = (List<User>) dbSession.createCriteria(User.class)
          .add(Restrictions.eq("nameOfFieldInUserClass", value))                
          .list();
```

"nameOfFieldInUserClass" is name of restriction field in User, **not name of column in DB**.

and for distinct you can use

```
setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("nameOfField")));
```